# Configure embedded tomcat with Gradle

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea, gradle, build

I was trying to run [sample app](https://github.com/habuma/SpringInActionExamples/tree/master/Chapter_05/Spittr) given in [Spring in action](http://www.manning.com/walls5/)(4th edition) but not able to configure tomcat with in build.gradle script,I have try to put the tomcat plugin with in script as

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'idea'
**apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'**

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:$springVersion"
    compile "com.h2database:h2:$h2Version"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:$hibernateValidatorVersion"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$commonsLangVersion"

    compile "javax.servlet:jstl:$jstlVersion"
    providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:$servletApiVersion"
    providedCompile "javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:$jspApiVersion"
    providedCompile "javax.el:javax.el-api:$jspElVersion"

  **classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.2'**

  **def tomcatVersion = '7.0.59'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
       "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}",
       "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"**

    testCompile "junit:junit-dep:$junitVersion"
    testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:$springVersion"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockitoVersion"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:$hamcrestVersion"
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://maven.springframework.org/release' }
    maven { url 'http://maven.springframework.org/milestone' }
    maven { url 'http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'http://download.java.net/maven/2' }
    mavenCentral()
    **jcenter()**
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.1'
}

war {
        baseName = 'spittr'
}
```

But it always fails build giving error:

```
Plugin with id 'com.bmuschko.tomcat' not found.
```

I have encapsulate settings in ** that I have used for tomcat configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading [the documentation for that plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin), you need to specify the dependency and the repository in the `buildscript` section of your gradle build - this will be loaded / built before the main build script.

Remove the plugin and repository as you currently have them in the file, and try adding this whole block of code to the top of your gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.2'
    }
}
```